# Google Cloud Endpoints return List

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

[image]

The First method is the original method from Google endpoints sample, it return a value

The Second Method is mine, it return null

i'm not sure, is it possible to return List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** return collections (Sets, Lists, etc) as stated on [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#return_types_and_request_body_types). Suggestion is to use com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse as its brings several built in benefits like paging.

Eg

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getAllTopics", path= "getAllTopics")
    public CollectionResponse<Topic> listEvent(
            @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
            @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

        List<Topic> execute = //fetch from datastore

        return CollectionResponse.<Topic> builder().setItems(execute)
                .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
    }
```